# WPF data grid selected item unselect

Tags: wpf

helo. i have problem. when i want to clear my data grid I am having such a problem.when datagrid item is selected i want click to button and clear data grid.but happened this error.

> Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
>   Parameter name: index

```
object item =dg_autoqeydiyyat.SelectedItem;
string ID = (dg_autoqeydiyyat.SelectedCells[0].Column.GetCellContent(item) as TextBlock).Text;
string NAME = (dg_autoqeydiyyat.SelectedCells[2].Column.GetCellContent(item) as TextBlock).Text;
txb_auto2qeydno.Text = ID;
txb_auto2nomresi.Text = NAME;
```

Comment: what you want, unselect all rows of grid or remove all rows?

Comment: unselect all rows or remove all rows there is no difference.i dont change object value "item" where  object item=dg_autoqeydiyyat.SelectedItem